# Adding support to handle ttf font file

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to write a application so that it can handle .ttf font file. The behaviour is when user click the ttf from explorer. my application should popup.

I tried the to add the below entry but it is not working.

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />    
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT">
            </category>           
            <data android:mimeType="application/x-font-ttf"/> 
     </intent-filter>
```

Below are the logs which i got through I try top choose ttf file.

> 11-28 10:19:08.510: W/System.err(22775):
>   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle
>   Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW
>   dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/yogiHindi.ttf typ= (has extras) }

Comment: you have to specify the activity associated with that particular intent in the manifest

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you haven't associated any activity to that intent in your manifest. That is causing the block. Declare the activity associated to it before this intent..

See like this..

```
<activity android:name="xxxxx"
              android:label="xxxx">

<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />    
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT">
        </category>           
        <data android:mimeType="application/x-font-ttf"/> 
 </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```